# Run python file outside Docker container that imports a python file outside Docker container

Tags: python, docker, import, command-line

So I have a simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /home
RUN apt-get -y update 
RUN apt install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa 
RUN apt install -y python3
```

It runs good with:

```
sudo docker build -t sample-image .
```

First I run my docker:

```
sudo docker run -t -d --name mycontainername sample-image:latest
```

If I run:

```
sudo docker exec -i mycontainername python3 < helloworld.py
```

It works fine:

> hello from docker

And then, I want to run a script a.py that imports a class_b from b.py. Note that a.py, b.py and helloworld.py are **only** in mi local computer, so they **does not exist inside the container**. a.py, b.py and helloworld.py are in the same folder

```
sudo docker exec -i mycontainername python3 < a.py
```

It says

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'

a.py:

```
import b
print("Hello world")
```

I think that the module 'b' is searched in the directory /home inside the docker. But putting the module inside the docker is not the solution I want, since I'm constantly editing that file

I'm constantly modifying a.py and b.py so I would want a command to run a.py with a command line like the following (I don't want to create the entire container over and over whenever I make a little change in the scripts):

```
sudo docker exec -i mycontainername python3 < a.py
```

Is there any command to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't sound like Docker is the tool you're looking for here.  In typical use you'd package your complete application into an image, not just the language runtime, and `docker run` the container would run the whole thing without manually providing a script name or external source code.  Does your host OS already have a usable Python installation (MacOS and most Linux distributions come with it by default)?

Comment: Yes, I have Python installed. I wanted to use containers to be sure about the configuration of all the libraries working with my scripts. In other words I don't want to finish my scripts, then try it in another machine and fail. But I think "volume" is the tool that I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David that maybe you don't need to involve docker here, but if  you really do then volumes will do what you need. You can map a directory in your local machine to a directory in the running container.

For example, if I create a directory called `src`and in it I create two files - a.py:

```
import b
print("hello from a")
```

and b.py

```
print("hello from b")
```

Now run a container from your image with local `src` mapped to your container working directory:

`docker run -it -d --name mycontainername -v $(pwd)/src:/home sample-image:latest`

now you can run `a.py` in the container:

`docker exec -i mycontainername python3 a.py`

you should see

```
hello from b
hello from a
```

All good so far. Now on your local machine, edit `src/b.py` or `src/a.py` and try that `docker exec` on the same running container, and the changes will have taken effect in the container.